# Support libraries 22.1.1 and Drawable Tinting

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Two weeks ago google released new support libraries, where the v4 library gives you the possibility to "use" the Lollipop feature of tinting drawables.

However so far I only managed to do this programmatically. There you wrap the drawable object, which basically returns you a new drawable which allows you to tint it.

*Question:* Now I wanted to ask whether it is possible to tint drawables via xml. The standard Lollipop way won't work with AppCompat.

Comment: YOu mean the TintImageView?

Comment: No I actually mean tintings for drawables. Like so https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically It won't work through the XML.I also failed it to work it through the XML but it works well if I do it programmatically.

Comment: But not every result is achievable programmitcally. How would you do, say  a drawable selector for a CheckedTextView?

Comment: Well I did it once for making my own FavouriteButton. I made a class overriding the CheckBox then override the onDraw method like this

            if (isChecked() || isPressed()) {
            getBackground().setColorFilter(accentColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        } else {
            getBackground().setColorFilter(normalColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }